# How to vertically and horizontally center a div using javascript and css margin?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am currently trying to center a rectangle in an image with only using javascript (no css center properties). However, even if the numbers are right, the showing is wrong.
To do this, I use the following code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".img-zoom-container").css("width", $("#myimage").width());
    $(".img-zoom-container").css("height", $("#myimage").height());
    
    $("#lens_container").css("width", ($("#myimage").width() - $("#lens").width()));
    $("#lens_container").css("height", ($("#myimage").height() - $("#lens").height()));
    $("#lens_container").css("top", ($("#lens").height() / 2));
    $("#lens_container").css("left", ($("#lens").width() / 2));
    
});
```

```css
.img-zoom-container
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#lens
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

#lens_container
{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-zoom-container">
    <div id="lens"></div>
    <div id="lens_container"></div>
    <img id="myimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x160.png?text=Testing Image" alt="">
</div>
```

The item I am trying to center is the `#lens_container` div (appears blue on screen). I also have a white square (`#lens` div) of size 50px by 50px. I would like to center and to size the blue rectangle in order to have half of the square width at each side of the blue rectangle and same with height. However, as you can see when trying the code, it is not the case although the maths are correct.

I do not know if you can understand my needs, but I would really appreciate help there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. If you refer to me saying using no CSS i meant by it to not use any css center properties.

Comment: Why, though? This is exactly what [CSS flexbox is for](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and has been for years, which works without anyone even needing JS to be turned on.

Comment: May I ask why? Because window resize makes that positioning no longer relevant, so you would need to re-calculate and adjust.

Comment: Because I need the blue rectangle to be centered AND sized in relation to the white square. If it is possible to do this 2 things directly with some pretty css properties I would not be against to try them out.
And for the window resize, it is a problem I had not take in account.

Comment: The output of your code seems to work quite well in the code snippet (once I give it a real image). You can click the "Run code snippet" button to see for yourself. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: In the code snippet you can clearly see that the left margin is smaller than the rigth margin, and the top margin is smaller than the bottom margin.

Comment: Your description is very confusing.  Which element are you trying to center, and what element is it supposed to be in the center of?

Comment: I am trying to center the blue rectangle (```#lens_container```) in the red rectangle (```.img-zoom-container```) which is the size of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

First, `position: absolute` means to position the item "to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block" ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)). The parent element ".img-zoom-container" is not positioned. The initial container block would be `<body>`, which has some padding by default.

So your `#lens_container` is positioned relative to `<body>` of the iframe, which is probably not what you expected. Moreover, `<body>` by default has a non-zero padding size. You may see it clearer if you simply use CSS to position everything to `top: 0` and `left: 0`:

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.img-zoom-container
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 600px;
    height: 160px;
}

#lens
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#lens_container
{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    width: 550px;
    height: 110px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-zoom-container">
    <div id="lens"></div>
    <div id="lens_container"></div>
    <img id="myimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x160.png?text=Testing Image" alt="">
</div>
```

To have both `#lens` and `#lens_container` positioned relative to `.img-zoom-container`, you have to give `.img-zoom-container` a "position" value so it can be the "position ancestor":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".img-zoom-container").css("width", $("#myimage").width());
    $(".img-zoom-container").css("height", $("#myimage").height());
    
    $("#lens_container").css("width", ($("#myimage").width() - $("#lens").width()));
    $("#lens_container").css("height", ($("#myimage").height() - $("#lens").height()));
    $("#lens_container").css("top", ($("#lens").height() / 2));
    $("#lens_container").css("left", ($("#lens").width() / 2));
    
});
```

```css
.img-zoom-container
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative; /** this line **/
}

#lens
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

#lens_container
{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-zoom-container">
    <div id="lens"></div>
    <div id="lens_container"></div>
    <img id="myimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x160.png?text=Testing Image" alt="">
</div>
```

It's still 1-2 pixels off. That is because you didn't take the border width into consideration (your second issue). You'd get a better result once you clear your head and think how you want the border widths to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on its container, you could just set an ID on your div like:

CONTENT .

Then in javascript, if there is an event to center it, you could make a function like:

```
function centerDivItem() {
    document.getElementById("id1").style.alignContent = "center"
}
```

And then, as I said, call it from another place.